# mmap vs fgetc to avoid cache misses

Tags: c, unix, io

I have a program where I read a file with fgetc() and one question asked is "does by using mmap() and unmap() can we reduce the amount of cache misses?"

To test it I wrote a dirty piece of code that given an argument on the command line, use mmap and the address returned by mmap or fgetc to read a file character by character and used valgrind --tool=cachegrind on my program to measure the number of cache misses and mmap does not reduce the number of cache misses by about but increase it

I have searched the Internet all day to find useful resources to help me understand why it does this. While I can see that by loading our file into the memory because it is loaded in a contiguous memory zone and we read from the first character to the last, why does it increase cache misses?.

I am looking for any particular resources or explanation that might help me understand what's really going on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are several caches. I guess you are talking about the kernel file system cache (or [page cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache)), not about the [CPU cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache).

You could use the [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) syscall to give hints (after `mmap`, or pass `MAP_POPULATE` to [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)) with memory mapping, or use [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) to give hints (before `read`) for file I/O.

If using [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) you probably want some larger buffer (e.g. 64Kbytes or more), see [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html). Notice that GNU `glibc` [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) may be able to `mmap` with the `m` extension in the mode.

See also [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html). And [linuxatemyram](http://linuxatemyram.com/).

Don't hope for miracles, the bottleneck is the hardware disk IO.